# Applying background to selected scenaros in cucumber (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

In cucumber, is it possible to apply `Background` to 4 out of 6 `Scenarios` in .feature file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, read the [wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background):

> Background allows you to add some context to the scenarios in a single
>   feature. A Background is much like a scenario containing a number of
>   steps. The difference is when it is run. The background is run before
>   each of your scenarios but after any of your Before Hooks.

Split your examples in several scenarios or use a single step in each of your 4 examples to do what you want to do in a background scope.